# Keycloak: Forgot password JWT parsing error

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to test "forgot password" link in Keycloak. I get the email but when I click on the link in the email, I see error on UI as **Invalid Request**

In the server log, I see this

> 13:51:03,602 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-36)
>   type=EXECUTE_ACTION_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=fidesque, clientId=null,
>   userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_code, reason='Failed
>   to parse JWT'

Any clue what I may be missing ?

regards,

Venky

Answer (score 0):

The error is gone after updating to latest version of Keycloak i.e 4.7.0

Comment: I was too fast I guess. The issue is not resolved. I updated to 4.8.0 but still it occurs. Can some help ?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue

Comment: do you still have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I still have same issue. No clue yet :(